# How can I display project explorer side by side with editor in eclips?

Tags: eclipse, layout

I was running my app when suddenly the layout of eclips changed.Now, the project explorer is at the top and the editor below it.What I want is the explorer to be to the left side and the editor to the right.Just like it used to be.It might be simple issue but very annoying as I can't see the files without having to scroll down in the explorer window.I tried reset perspective but didn't work! Any ideas?

Comment: Try drag and drop :)

Comment: That worked like magic man! I love u!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the menu command **Window** > **Reset Perspective** to restore it to it's default layout. Otherwise, you can move Views around however you like to get a custom layout.